# Modifying a configuration file in several nodes

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, configuration-files

my question is very straightforward, I need to modify the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file in 80 nodes, so I wonder how can I make it automatically. Is it there any tool to manage those kind of configuration in multiple nodes?? Thanks

All the nodes in the cluster use Centos 5 x86_64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of tools and more or less advanced solutions - like Pupper or Chef. rdist is nice tool as well to propagate files to multiple boxes - it's something like a distributed rsync and you can prepare config that will containg what and where should be uploaded.

But if you don't want to go so far you can use simpler way to achieve it.
If you have ssh keys propagated you can easy copy the file to multiple boxes:

```
#!/bin/bash
for host in `cat ./host_list_file`; do
 scp ./sshd_config ${host}:/etc/ssh/sshd_config
done
```

Comment: and if you don't have... then you can use `expect` to automate password typing

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Python [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) module. Using that you can implement SFTP transfer to the multiple nodes with only few lines of code.